# Let $G$ be a group, $a \in G$. Prove that for all $g \in G$, $|a| = |g^{-1}ag|$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification

I am stuck on this problem. Let's just consider the case where $|a|$ is finite. So $|a| = n$ where $n$ is the least positive integer such that $a^{n} = e$.

First I need to show that $|g^{-1}ag| \le n$.

I notice that
$g^{-1}a^{n}g = g^{-1}eg = g^{-1}g = e$. But does this imply that $(g^{-1}ag)^{n} = e$? If so, why? This is where I am stuck.

Comment: Did you try to compute what $(g^{-1}ag)^n$ is? You may start from $n=2$.

Comment: ah. Thank you @Mark

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conjugation is an isomorphism. Isomorphisms preserve the orders of elements. There is no need to restrict to finite orders.